# WiX: Conditionally grant log on as a service right

Tags: wix

I'm using `User` from the `WixUtilExtenion` library to grant a user the log on as a service right:

```
...
<Property Id="SVCUSERNAME" Value="LocalSystem" />
...
<Component Id="MyApp">
  <File Id="MyApp.exe" Name="MyApp.exe" />

  <util:User Id="UpdateUserLogonAsService" UpdateIfExists="yes" CreateUser="no" Name="[SVCUSERNAME]" LogonAsService="yes" />

  <ServiceInstall Id="MyApp" Type="ownProcess" Name="MyApp" DisplayName="MyApp"
    Description="MyApp" Start="auto" Account="[SVCUSERNAME]" Password="[SVCPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes">
  </ServiceInstall>

  <ServiceControl Id="MyApp" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="MyApp" Wait="no" />
</Component>
```

The property `SVCUSERNAME` is changed if the user specified a different user, otherwise it defaults to the Local System account. Rights assignment will not work for Local System (which has this right anyway), so I only want to attempt to add the right if the `SVCUSERNAME` property is *not* LocalSystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the User in its own component so that you can condition it without also conditioning your service install and file.  Under the user component add
`<Condition><![CDATA[SVCUSERNAME ~<> "LocalSystem" AND SVCUSERNAME ~<> "SYSTEM"]]</Condtion>`.  I included SYSTEM since it is an alias that the user might specify for the system account.